# Bypass Avira blocking one of my scripts

Tags: windows, avira

I created a VB program to simplify a routine for me, but every time I try to launch it, Avira always blocks the action that is taking place in the C:\ drive.

It's a little annoying to have to stop Avira every time, so is there any other solution?

Comment: What does your question have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: @slhck I think Ubuntu has a different GUI. However, saying that. jugurtha should have specified the difference in versions

Comment: @BradlySpicer Avira does not offer anything for Linux (anymore). And the OP is talking about the C drive, so...

Comment: @slhck very good point. I didn't think of that. I can only assume that jugurtha is confused and should re-word the question

Answer (score 4):

You want to create an exception. Avira's website [explains how to do that](http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1257):

> Open the Avira Control Center. Click on Extras → Configuration.
>
> [image]
>
> Click on General → Advanced Protection → Application filter → Allowed.
>
> [image]
>
> Click on the button with the three dots
>
> [image]
>
> In the next window, please search for the blocked application (exe
>   file) and click on Open
>
> [image]